# How to add a mask map of a white scratch on a material in Unity which stays white when base color goes black?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to generate a scratch on a door car object so I need to added on the material of the car using a map but that map works like an opacity: when the door color is black the scratch goes black (I need to keep it white)

I am working on Substance Designer and I have generated normal and mask maps of the scratch and added them to the unity material

I expect the scratch to stay white but when the material color goes black, the scratch goes black